# Unmarshaling <tag value="val"/> to Tag string in Go

Tags: go, xml-parsing

Say that I've got a Go struct defined as follows:

```
type MyType struct {
    FieldA string
    FieldB string
    FIeldC string
}
```

and XML that corresponds to it that looks like this:

```
<obj>
    <fieldA value="apple"/>
    <fieldB value="banana"/>
</obj>
```

where FieldA and FieldB are mandatory, and FieldC is optional. How do I specify the struct tags so as to get the field's value from the "value" attribute? This:

```
FieldA string `xml:"fieldA>value,attr"`
FieldB string `xml:"fieldB>value,attr"`
FieldC string `xml:"fieldC>value,attr,omitempty"`
```

generates "xml: fieldA>value chain not valid with attr flag" and this:

```
FieldA string `xml:"fieldA"`
FieldB string `xml:"fieldB"`
FieldC string `xml:"fieldC,omitempty"`
```

doesn't generate an error, but doesn't find the values of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support both XML and JSON, you will have to define a simple type and implement the [`xml.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler) and [`xml.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) interfaces on it, here's an example:

```
type Field string

func (f Field) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    v := struct {
        Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
    }{string(f)}
    return e.EncodeElement(v, start)
}

func (f *Field) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var v struct {
        Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
    }
    err := d.DecodeElement(&v, &start)
    *f = Field(v.Value)
    return err
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/b7zm6I0DT0)

Comment: This is a great compromise between changing only the _name_ of the types of the struct elements, while still being able to handle the weirdness of the XML. I'll play with it further. Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented your solution in the actual code. The only wrinkle is that you can't return a Field value from a function requiring a string, but that's a minor problem. In the actual code, I'm using StringField, BooleanField, etc. This is really an elegant solution, thank you.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester glad to help! and also yes you can, just convert it to a string: `func getStr(f Field) string { return string(f) }`. it is an alias for a string after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the form of `fieldA>value` because elements of this "path" denote elements and `value` is not an element in your case.

If you want to get a value out from an attribute of a child element, you can create a wrapper type for it.

For example:

```
type Field struct {
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}
```

Using this your `MyType` struct:

```
type MyType struct {
    FieldA Field `xml:"fieldA"`
    FieldB Field `xml:"fieldB"`
    FieldC Field `xml:"fieldC"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    mt := MyType{}
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &mt); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", mt)
}

const src = `<obj>
    <fieldA value="apple"/>
    <fieldB value="banana"/>
</obj>`
```

Output (try it on the <kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Rmw-DW3aiV)</kbd>):

```
{FieldA:{Value:apple} FieldB:{Value:banana} FieldC:{Value:}}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to handle both XML and JSON with one struct, in the XML you should use the content of the element to hold the data (and not the `value` attribute), for example:

```
<obj>
    <fieldA>apple</fieldA>
    <fieldB>banana</fieldB>
</obj>
```

And the struct to model this:

```
type MyType struct {
    FieldA string `xml:"fieldA"`
    FieldB string `xml:"fieldB"`
    FieldC string `xml:"fieldC"`
}
```

This same struct can unmarshal from JSON:

```
const src2 = `{"fieldA": "apple", "fieldB": "banana"}`

mt = MyType{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src2), &mt); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", mt)
```

Output: the same:

```
{FieldA:apple FieldB:banana FieldC:}
{FieldA:apple FieldB:banana FieldC:}
```

Try this variant (with JSON) on the <kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2GcFLdmEs_)</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The issue here is that I need to be able to unmarshal from either JSON or XML. In JSON, the format is `{"fieldA": "apple", "fieldB": "banana"}`. Logically, the value belongs to the parent, not a child, so I don't have the freedom to introduce a wrapper.

Comment: @ScottDeerwester You didn't mention anything related to json in your question. If you want to handle both XML and JSON with one struct, then use the element content to hold the value, not its attribute.

Comment: I apologize, the reason for not mentioning JSON was brevity. I really don't have the freedom to change either the struct definition or the XML format. The latter is from [the FHIR standard](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/) and the former from [the Go version of the standard](https://github.com/intervention-engine/fhir).

Comment: If you can't change the XML neither the JSON, you can't do this with one struct unless you implement custom marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I wonder if I could build a custom XML unmarshaller/marshaller  to recognize the "value" attribute for _everything_, instead of on an item-by-item basis?

Comment: @ScottDeerwester check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by introducing a `Field` struct that has a Value member:

```
type MyType struct {
    FieldA Field `xml:"fieldA"`
    FieldB Field `xml:"fieldB"`
    FIeldC Field `xml:"fieldC"`
}

type Field struct {
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}
```

This should do the trick. Here is full example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type MyType struct {
    FieldA Field `xml:"fieldA"`
    FieldB Field `xml:"fieldB"`
    FieldC Field `xml:"fieldC"`
}

type Field struct {
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func deserializeMyType(reader io.Reader) (MyType, error) {
    myType := MyType{}
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)
    err := decoder.Decode(&myType)
    if err != nil {
        return MyType{}, err
    }

    return myType, nil
}

func main() {
    inputXML := `<obj>
    <fieldA value="apple"/>
    <fieldB value="banana"/>
</obj>`

    xmlReader := strings.NewReader(inputXML)
    myType, err := deserializeMyType(xmlReader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%#v\n", myType)
}
```

The output for your sample XML would be this:

```
main.MyType{FieldA:main.Field{Value:"apple"}, FieldB:main.Field{Value:"banana"}, FieldC:main.Field{Value:""}}
```

You can find other examples for derserializing XML attributes in the go sources at [golang.org/src/encoding/xml/example_test.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/xml/example_test.go).